# Is this a right way to code a contents of view in controller, for a comboBox

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

```
new sap.m.ComboBox({
id: "samplecombo",
items: "{path:'sample>/'}",
content: [ new sap.ui.core.Item({
text: "sample>Items", // string
key: "sample>Items" // string
}) 
]                                                   
})
```

this code is used to call a combobox within the controller, is this code right as am getting an error stating

> "Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element
> sap.m.ComboBox".

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests you have to provide a template or factory function.

`items` and `content` are two different aggregations (and I think `ComboBox` doesn't even have the `content` aggregation). If you want to render items, you have to add all the info to the `items` attribute. [Here in the docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) they have explained this in more detail. And [here is the API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.AggregationBindingInfo%23overview) where the parameters for a proper binding info object are documented.

As you can see you can provide the attribute `template` to your binding info.

```js
new sap.m.ComboBox({
    id: "samplecombo",
    items: {
        path:'sample>/',
        template: new sap.ui.core.Item({
            text: "sample>Items",
            key: "sample>Items"
        }) 
    }                                               
})
```